# Calculating the annualized return of the VIX

Tags: r

I need to calculate the annualized return of the VIX and it's Futures by using daily data from six and a half years.
I tried to use the R-function Return.annualized from the PerformanceAnalytics-package:

```
 Return.annualized(vix,scale=252,geometric=TRUE)
```

But all R shows is "INF" as a result. Am I wrong by just letting the daily index values run through this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data must be corrupted. Can you run `summary` or `hist` on them to see whether there are NAs or prices that are not plausible?

The problem is that you work on prices. You should work on the returns of VIX:
What about this:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(xts)
data = read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE)

vix = xts(data$VIX, order.by = as.Date(data$Date,"%d.%M.%Y")  )
vix.ret = Return.calculate(vix, method = "discrete")
Return.annualized(vix.ret,scale=252,geometric=TRUE)
```

Comment: There are no missing values and the index ranges from 10.32 to 52.65.

Comment: Can you post your data? e.g. upload it to gdrive and share the link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-j4esZ-O8IbSHNiV3gxSWo0NEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I got the data. Please post more code. You have to construct an xts object. How do you do that?

Comment: I just put the VIX and Date into an xts object:
    vix <- xts(vixts, order.by=datevix)

Comment: There is no column name "vixts" ... please post your code.

Comment: Sorry, I converted the VIX column into a time series and from this one if have made the xts object: 
vixts <- ts(vixdata$VIX)
vix <- xts(vixts, order.by=datevix)
Return.annualized(vix,scale=252,geometric=TRUE)

Comment: I edited my answer. Please have a look